# When does "caller save" becomes a MUST?

Tags: x86, arm, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm reading H&P: Computer Architecture a Quantitative Approach 6th ediiton.

In App.A page A-19 a paragraph states:

> There are times when caller save must be used because of access patterns to globally visible variables in two different procedures. For example, suppose we have a procedure P1 that calls procedure P2, and both procedures manipulate the global variable x. If P1 had allocated x to a register, it must be sure to save x to a location known by P2 before the call to P2. A compiler’s ability to discover when a called procedure may access register-allocated quantities is complicated by the possibility of separate compilation.

My question is: How is that possible? Isn't global variables are placed in the **global data segment** and they have their own memory address? How can they be allocated to registers?

I tried to research to understand this but didn't find anything useful!
Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing. I think they are talking about the case when the code is manipulating a global variable and the compiler could load it once in a register and do the manipulation there. When there's a call the compiler is forced to store the result back into the global variable. See for example [this](https://godbolt.org/z/ec4ed7494) where `foo` loads `x` once and store the final result back to it, while `foo2` loads and stores `x` twice due to the call to `bar` (`x` has static linkage but static global vars can still "escape" the translation unit due to pointers).

Comment: I wouldn't call that caller-*save*, it's not about how the calling convention manages registers, it's about what data is being kept in registers. i.e. correctness of register allocation ("enregistering") of globally-visible variables. It's a spill (and possibly reload) for another reason. At any non-inline function call boundary, functions that don't know about each other's internals must have all globally-reachable memory in sync with the abstract machine.  (Global vars, and anything that might possibly be pointed-to by global vars, and static vars that could be accessed by global functions.)

Comment: Also, this illustrate a potential benefit of the `pure` annotation in GCC (and most likely Clang).  A '`pure` external would also be fine with this. Ie, `foo2()` does not need to save/reload `x` as it is known not to change.  Ie, add `int bar(void) __attribute__((pure));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers can sometimes see the internal implementation of a function that is called by another function it is currently working on.  In some of those cases, it can manipulate the calling convention and also use additional alias analysis for improvement, knowing the implementation details of both caller and callee.

However, the use of the term "caller saves" seems out of line in describing these scenarios.  Caller saves generally used to refer to a specific subset of the registers that have been designated as scratch registers, aka call clobbered.  These scratch registers are presumed wiped out by a function call, so in normal function calling (when the callee's internal implementation details are unknown) they should not be used to hold data that is live across such function call.  If needed, compilers will move such data to memory or to call preserved (callee saves) registers.  Though they can, they don't necessarily reload to the same register immediately after the call, so the caller-saves pattern is not always used they way the phrase implies.

Callee saves register, better described as call preserved registers, are used in a pattern of save in function prologue, use at will in function body, restore their original (function entry) value in function epilogue.  Their advantage is in not having to save/restore inside the function body — instead just once in prologue/epilogue.  This is particularly useful when the function body contains loops.  The pattern requires saving original values in registers and restoring those original values back to the exact registers in returning to the caller.

The implication of the phrase caller-saves is of a similar pattern — save caller-saves register (say, to local stack memory), make a call, then restore that register.  However, compilers rarely use that pattern, instead using scratch registers for data that isn't live across a call, and using other storage (memory or call preserved registers) for data that is live across the call.

If P1 caches global `x` in a register then it needs to save it back to the known location before a call that it makes to P2, if P2 uses `x` (or it isn't known whether or not P2 uses `x`).  This applies whether P1 caches `x` in a *callee- or caller- saves register* (or in local stack memory for some reason).

It seems confusing to use the well-known term "caller saves" (which designates the scratch register subset or a register in this subset) for the scenario they are describing.  The term caller saves it seems to me, is more about the preservation requirements across a call for one's own values rather than saving of cached memory-based (global or other) variables to share with a caller or callee.

Comment: Good answer; same thoughts in more detail that Margaret and I commented with.  I was really surprised to see Hennessy and Patterson using that terminology.  I still think it's a mistake, or an attempt to make an analogy that came out maybe more misleading than helpful.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I agree.  My bad on searching for that in latest edition: I've been looking at Computer Org and Design, P&H.

Comment: My paper copy of 2nd edition (from undergrad CS) of P&H CA: A Quantitative Approach has appendices about (A) integer and floating-point ALUs, (B) vector processors, (C) survey of RISCs, (D) 80x86, and (E) coherence protocols.  No obvious place to look in more detail for a paragraph like that, and it's paper so I can't search quickly.

Comment: Section on [Procedure Invocation Options](https://archive.org/details/computerarchitectureaquantitativeapproach6thedition/page/n667/mode/2up), short and abstract, more appropriate maybe for a h/w designer audience.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: How is that possible? Isn't global variables are placed in the global data segment and they have their own memory address? How can they be allocated to registers?

Load store architectures and even those that are not it is often best to keep the variable in a register......while you are using it.

```
extern unsigned int x;
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int);

unsigned int fun0 ( void )
{
    return(fun1(x+1)+x);
}


00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e59f4018    ldr r4, [pc, #24]   ; 24 <fun0+0x24>
   8:   e5940000    ldr r0, [r4]
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun1>
  14:   e5943000    ldr r3, [r4]
  18:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  1c:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
  20:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  24:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

we can see the optimization of keeping the address to x in r4 a preserved register I guess that is callee saved, I hate those terms.  Non-volatile.  Instead of keeping the address itself on the stack costing stack space and memory cycle or reading it from memory/flash again for each access, costing cycles.

This function demonstrates the statement, first

```
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e59f4018    ldr r4, [pc, #24]   ; 24 <fun0+0x24>
   8:   e5940000    ldr r0, [r4]
```

at this point the value x is allocated to r0
c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
at this point r0 is no longer x but an intermediate value.

r4 remains the address to x across the nested call(s).

```
  14:   e5943000    ldr r3, [r4]
```

so it has to assign it to a register again, now r3.

```
  18:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  1c:   e0800003    add r0, r0, r3
```

but if the function were within the optimization domain

```
extern unsigned int x;
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int z)
{
    return(x+2);
}

unsigned int fun0 ( void )
{
    return(fun1(x+1)+x);
}


00000014 <fun0>:
  14:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 28 <fun0+0x14>
  18:   e5930000    ldr r0, [r3]
  1c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  20:   e1a00080    lsl r0, r0, #1
  24:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  28:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

now the compiler does not need to go back to memory for x,

note x+1+2+x = 2x+3 = 2x+1+1 = (2x+1)+1

Yes it is inlined, but that is the kind of thing you would need to know in order to not in this case need to re-read x.

If we knew what P2 was doing with the global then we could

```
push {r4, lr}
ldr  r4, =x
ldr  r4, [r4]
add  r0, r4, #1
bl   fun1
add  r0,r0,r4
pop  {r4, lr}
bx   lr
```

and keep x in r4 for the duration of fun0.

Would resemble something like this

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int);
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int a )
{
    return(fun1(a+1)+a);
}

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e1a04000    mov r4, r0
   8:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <fun1>
  10:   e0800004    add r0, r0, r4
  14:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

the variable a is kept in r4 for the duration of fun0, across the call, yes it is not global but this shows how the compiler could/would treat it if the compiler knew, as it knows with a local variable, that the callee cannot modify it.  The same optimization would apply if the language allowed a mechanism and/or the optimizer knew that the callee was not modifying the variable.

You have the problem of the callee being in a different object, so you have to construct the code as if it could modify it and then would be some link time optimization.

so.c

```
int x;
int fun1 ( int);
int main ( void )
{
    return(fun1(x+1)+x);
}
```

one.c

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x)
{
    return(0);
}


00008018 <main>:
    8018:   ea00008a    b   8248 <fun1.constprop.0>

00008248 <fun1.constprop.0>:
    8248:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
    824c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

with link time optimization it removed x completely in this case.

```
unsigned int fun1 ( unsigned int x)
{
    return(x+1);
}

00008018 <main>:
    8018:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    801c:   ea00008a    b   824c <fun1>

0000824c <fun1>:
    824c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
    8250:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

okay this took some work but it just inlined it which IMO is what you would probably do anyway if you could see into P2.

so.c

```
int x;
extern int fun0();
int main ( void )
{
    x=5;
    return(fun0());
}
```

zero.c

```
extern int x;
int fun1 ( int );
int fun0 ( void )
{
    return(fun1(x+1)+x);
}
```

one.c

```
int fun1 ( int x)
{
    return(x+1);
}
```

with link time optimization, meaning the compiler can see into the nested functions to see if they mess with x.

```
00008018 <main>:
    8018:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
    801c:   e59f3008    ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; 802c <main+0x14>
    8020:   e3a0000c    mov r0, #12
    8024:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    8028:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
    802c:   00018abc    .word   0x00018abc
```

No real surprise here.

x is allocated to r0, if you will, here

```
    8020:   e3a0000c    mov r0, #12
```

> I tried to research to understand this but didn't find anything useful! Thanks in advance for helping.

The research:

```
unsigned int x;
void fun ( void )
{
    x = x + 1;
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e59f200c    ldr r2, [pc, #12]   ; 14 <fun+0x14>
   4:   e5923000    ldr r3, [r2]
```

x is allocated to register r3 at this point in time.

```
   8:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
   c:   e5823000    str r3, [r2]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
```

research complete.